# Javascript. Where will the return value (13) will be put in?

Tags: javascript

Code 1 has no variable for the function call... so my question here is.... where will the return value (13) will be put in? since there is no any variable for function call in code 1. Code 2 has a variable var thevariableithink wherein it is where the answer 13 will be put in since 8 + 5 = 13.

```
code 1:
var addFiveplease = function(thenumberithink) {
return thenumberithink + 5;
};

//doesn't have any variable so there's no place where the 13 will be stored.
addFiveplease(8)  

                        //VS

code 2:
var addFiveplease = function(thenumberithink) {
return thenumberithink + 5;
};

//has variable var thevariableithink where 13 will be stored.
var thevariableithink = addFiveplease(8)
```

Answer (score 1):

> where will the return value (13) will be put in? since there is no any variable for function call in code 1

In `code1` it won't be stored anywhere as you are not assigning the returned value to any variable.

Comment: do return also log string to the console? If yes... why? co'z I saw this ... http://hastebin.com/omufosesof.coffee

Comment: @jubilukbabawakis. what do you mean by _log string to console_? Are you talking about `console.log(addFiveplease(8) )` printing `13` in console?

Comment: NO... this another code here http://hastebin.com/omufosesof.coffee ... can u see it?

Comment: @jubilukbabawakis. That code is similar to your code, it needs to be assigned to be stored.

Comment: why does it prints? ... I thought return just returns values ... but why it prints? http://hastebin.com/omufosesof.coffee

Comment: @jubilukbabawakis Can you show whats happening there in a fiddle? Bcoz I don't see it printing anywhere(console).

Answer (score 0):

if the question is in case 1(`addFiveplease(8)`) what will happen to the value returned? then it won't be stored anywhere and since there is no reference to the value it will be available for garbage collection

Comment: do return also log string to the console? If yes... why? co'z I saw this ... http://hastebin.com/omufosesof.coffee